# grc: Highlight capture groups only?

Tags: regular-expression, colors, grc

Recently I came across `grc` and I find it really simple. However, I would like to highlight some chunks of regex-matched text. For example, `svn status` properties conflict highlight I hoped to work:

```
regexp=^.(C)
colours=black on_yellow
```

Unfortunately the first character gets yellow too, because `grc` doesn't seem to apply highlight to the capture group only. Is there any way to highlight the second character only? Or is there a better way to workaround (any other tool can be an option too, sure)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to check your regex with a tester like [regex101](https://regex101.com).

You might want to try [`colout`](http://nojhan.github.io/colout/), which is like an alternative to `grep --color`.

```
colout REGEX [COLOR] [STYLE]
```

Use `colout -r all` to list all resources.

AFAIK you can make your own theme and name it `colout_*.py` where * is the file extension.

I would use `grc` to permanently `alias` a command (although redirection doesn't seem to work well, e.g. try `ping` to an unknown host to see what I mean), `colout` for occasionally parsing files.

Other colourisers you might want to try
· [list of colourisers](https://inconsolation.wordpress.com/tag/color/)
· [highlight](http://www.andre-simon.de/doku/highlight/en/highlight.php) (which I use in OS X with [QLColorCode](https://github.com/anthonygelibert/QLColorCode))
· [pygments](http://pygments.org) (haven't tried this one yet)

EDIT
Use undocumented keyword [`unchanged`](https://github.com/garabik/grc/blob/master/grcat#L35). This works

```
regexp=^.(C)
colours=unchanged,black on_yellow
```

Comment: `colout` seems to be a good option, however I'm not sure if styles can cascade like `grc` styles. I'll check it as soon as possible.

Comment: It would be great. Could you please update your answer? (Sorry have no access to a desktop right now)

Comment: `colout` still seems to be the closest match to the question (especially it features some cool stuff), but I couldn't find any config files feature.

Comment: As far as I see, `colout -t` is the best choice, but it seems to use preinstalled themes. Not sure if I'm right.

Comment: Hi, sorry for late reply. No, I couldn't figure out how to configure `colout` so it could work as I want it to work at that time, and I simply threw it away.

Comment: Well, the regex is fine.

Comment: Oh man, that is very unexpected. :D I don't know why you haven't forgotten this question, and have no idea why you decided to proceed with `grc`  deeper. :) Thank you for the awesome update and efforts! Now my `svnc.sh status` will have great output.

Comment: By the way, this rule supports multiple groups. Let's say `regexp=^.(C)(D)` \n `colours=unchanged,black on_yellow,black on_green`. I'm impressed.

Comment: Ok, I see now how it works in full. The `regexp` option can specify the whole regexp and its groups. The `colours` option can refer to both whole string and matched groups using options split with `,`. Thus each field in the split string array can have its own color rule or can be simply empty. So, `unchanged` can be simply omitted.